# Power BI with SQL Analysis Services: how to "Hide" all not used tables from "Fields"

Tags: powerbi, simplify

When I work in Power BI Desktop connected to *SQL Analysis Services*, my model looks like this,

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jicu.png)

And the "Fields" tab on the right spans for more than a page long:

[Enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXaQS.png)

In reality I actually use only a few tables and a few columns in those tables + my measures.

To simplify that look, I can go to ellipses near each tables title, and hide that particular table. I also can do this on "model" tab, but in my case, when I have a few dozens of tables, it is time consuming.

Is there a way how to "hide" all not used tables  and columns, to help report consumers to comprehend the model and my calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also easily hide multiple fields in Power BI Desktop. The best place to do that is to go into the *Model* tab. Then select all fields that you want to hide (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> with selection), and then in the *Properties* tab beside it, turn the *Is Hidden* property to *On*.

Comment: Thank you Gowtham_7, that is exactly was I was needed